# X509Certificate2 Private Key

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to sign an envelope using a local machine certificate, when I send the request it's ignored "for invalid signature".

I have an old code that is working just fine on .Net Framework using X509Certificate (Microsoft.Web.Services.Security.X509)

```
X509Certificate cert = this.GetX509Certificate;
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(envelope);
signedXml.SigningKey = cert.Key; // This is working
```

[image]

Now I need to re-write the whole thing in .Net Core, and I'm using X509Certificate2 (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates)

the **cert.Key** doesn't exist. So I'm using the following:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = this.GetX509Certificate;

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(envelope);

Reference bodyReference = new Reference();
bodyReference.Uri = "#Body";
bodyReference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url;

XmlDsigExcC14NTransform trans = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
bodyReference.AddTransform(trans);
signedXml.AddReference(bodyReference);

signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";

signedXml.SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() // This is not working
```

[image]

Could the CspKeyContainerInfo difference be the issue here? and if so how can I change that?

I've also re-set the values for DigestMethod, SignatureMethod and CanonicalizationMethod to match the methods under the working code in .Net Framework.

Comment: The `X509Certificate` should have the `PrivateKey` property.

Comment: @WiktorZychla `PrivateKey` property is obsolete since .NET 4.6.

Comment: `SignedXml` got support for `RSACng` since .NET 4.6.2 (at least), so it isn't the problem. It is somewhere else.

Comment: @Crypt32 I've added more code, could I be messing it up by re-setting the DigestMethod, SignatureMethod and CanonicalizationMethod?

Comment: @Crypt32: I've been using it for ages and can't find any clear information it's obsolete. Is it mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_PrivateKey)?

Comment: @WiktorZychla it isn't in docs, it is practical experience. `PrivateKey` supports only legacy CSP (no ECC crypto). If the key is in KSP (even RSA), you are out of luck with this property. My strong recommendation is to not use this property in .NET 4.6+.

Comment: @Crypt32: SignedXml doesn't support ECC at all in net framework, it throws from ComputeSingatute no matter how you point to the private key. Also practical experience.

Comment: @WiktorZychla that's correct, classic .NET Framework does not support ECC, nor CNG/KSP. To my knowledge, `SignedXml` does support RSA stored in KSP in .NET Core, just tested it and it works. Computes and validates signature.

Comment: Did another test. RSA in CNG/KSP works perfectly in .NET 4.6.2